# Linkage between library name at include <name.h> and libname.o

Tags: c++, c, gcc, linker, shared-libraries

I'm reading [this site](http://l4u-00.jinr.ru/usoft/WWW/HOWTO/GCC-HOWTO-6.html) that says if I do:

```
include<name.h>
```

then my library object has the format libname.o. But for example, [this site](http://lampwww.epfl.ch/~fsalvi/docs/gcc/www.network-theory.co.uk/docs/gccintro/gccintro_16.html) says that the library name for include math.h is libm.a. What am I getting wrong here?

Comment: Are you sure it is libname.o? is it libname.so?

Comment: `#include` includes a header file (source code).  Linking compiled code with static (`.a`) or shared (`.so`) libraries is a separate step.

Answer (score 2):

The naming convention `name.h` and `libname.a` is just that, a convention. Many libraries follow it, but not all. In particular, many platforms have all the C library in just one file, `libc.a`, regardless of the classification into different headers. Others have the parts for the math library then extra in `libm.a`.

Comment: that' becaue he compiles with -lm? Also, how does the compiler knows that that libm.a is for math.h since its all binary?

Answer (score 1):

Library can `static` or `dynamic` library, static library will have name of the form `libname.a`, also called archive file, whereas dynamic lib will have `libname.so`, also called shared object(so).

Usually, as a convention, people follow a correlation `name.h` to `libname.*` for easy remberance :) but this is just a convention. You can follow your own naming while packaging a library.

When linking, we specified library using `-lname`, which got expanded to `libname.a` or `libname.so` by the linker automatically

Comment: o that' becaue he compiles with -lm? Also, how does the compiler knows that that libm.a is for math.h since its all binary?

Comment: Compiler does not. User have to supply that. Whenever, linker need a symbol to link with, it checks in supplied libs.